# Gson - Avoid unneccessary wrapper classes when serializing

Tags: java, gson, wrapper

I have a Json String:

```
{
    "Locations":{
        "Location":[{
            "elevation":"100",
            "latitude":"0",
            "longitude":"0",
            "name":"Ocean"
        },
        ...
    ]}
}
```

I want to serialize this into an array of `Location` classes using `Gson`:

```
public class Location {
    public double elevation;
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
    public String name;
}
```

Rather than making a `Locations` class and a wrapper class with a `Locations` field. Is this possible + how?

Comment: Just create the corresponding Maps and List and serialize those.  It would be done before you finished asking the question.

Comment: @HotLicks Example? I've never done it this way before

Comment: Create a Map containing elevation, latitude, longitude, name.  Put that Map in a List, put the List in a Map under the name "location".  Put that Map in a Map under the name "locations".  Serialize with your toolkit of choice.  If you wish, use the specific classes for your toolkit of choice rather than Map/List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```java
jsonStr = "...";

Class<? extends HashMap> mapType = new HashMap<String, Object>().getClass();
Map data = new Gson().fromJson(job.jobContext, mapType);

JsonObject locations = data.get("Locations").getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray locationAry = locations.get("Location").getAsJsonArray();

for(JsonElement jsonEle: locationAry) {
   Location loc = new Location();
   JsonObject jsLoc = jsonEle.getAsJsonObject();
   loc.elevation = jsLoc.get("elevation").getAsInt();
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could decouple this from Gson?

Comment: @clairharrison - Use plain old Java Maps and Lists and you can use pretty much any JSON kit to serialize it.

Comment: you mean to make it work with any JSON parser?  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `Locaitons` object and then the `Location` array. Below code is pure Gson:

```
String jsonAsText = "{\"Locations\":{\"Location\":[{\"elevation\":\"100\",\"latitude\":\"0\",\"longitude\":\"0\",\"name\":\"Ocean\"},{\"elevation\":\"100\",\"latitude\":\"0\",\"longitude\":\"0\",\"name\":\"Ocean\"}]}}";

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

java.lang.reflect.Type listType = new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<List<Location>>(){}.getType();

JsonArray locationJsonList = (JsonArray) ((JsonObject) gson.fromJson(jsonAsText, JsonObject.class).get("Locations")).get("Location");
List<Location> locatioList = gson.fromJson(locationJsonList, listType);
```